# List directories without a specific folder

Tags: linux, mac-osx, find

I need some help constructing a directory listing using 'find'?

An example directory structure looks something like this:

```
/ (root)
 - /foo
   - /folderA
   - /folderB
 - /bar
   - /folderA
     -/search
   - /folderB
```

What I want to find is a list of 'folderA' or 'folderB' directories that do NOT have a 'search' folder. Requested output would be:

```
/foo/folderA
/foo/folderB
/bar/folderB
```

I am assuming this can be accomplished with 'find' on a *nix system, but am pretty green with the command. All help is appreciated.

SOLVED:
Thank you Khaled for your response leading me in the right direction. Needed a slight modification to include the -E option, but the final solution looked like this:

`find -E . -regex '.*(folderA|folderB)' -type d '!' -exec test -d '{}/search' ';' -print`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find command like:

```
$ find . -regex ".*folder\(A\|B\)" -type d '!' -exec test -d '{}/search' ';' -print
```

Comment: i was testing this out, but am having an issue with the -regex portion. I need it to match on 'folderA|folderB', not 'folder(A|B)'. When I tried it, I was able to match `find . -regex ".*folderA" -type d -print` by itself, but not `find . -regex ".*\(folderA\|folderB\)" -type d -print` Do I need more than one regex. Word boundaries `\\b` didn't seem to help either

Comment: I think the issue is you escaping the pipe between `folderA|folderB`. You're already quoting it, so find is interpreting it as a literal `|` character.

Comment: found it. needed the -E option for find. Thanks so much for your help. Will post the final find in another answer for the exact string I used.

Comment: @jgoldschrafe2 I tried it without the escape and it still didn't work. The answer was the -E option for find: `find . -regex '.*(folderA|folderB)' -type d '!' -exec test -d '{}/search' ';' -print` doesn't work, but `find -E . -regex '.*(folderA|folderB)' -type d '!' -exec test -d '{}/search' ';' -print` does